# Simulation in a Google map

Tags: google-maps-api

I try to make something like this [site](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip2.htm) but I don't know how. I have found Google API for animation but how do I combine the animation [site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-animate) because I don't have the coordinates of the routing of [this service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel)?

[This site](http://www.kmcgraphics.com/google/) is like what I'm trying to make.

---

Added after ymirsson's answer: I try to make a custom SVG icon, to convert a PNG icon to SVG. The other problem I have is I can't stop it in end destination.  I try with the following code, like you wrote.

```
createPolyline(response,leg.end_location); 

function createPolyline(directionResult,end) { //same if(directionResult.routes[0].overview_path==end)
 stopCircle(); }; 

function stopCircle() { window.clearInterval(this.offsetId); this.setOptions({ icons: null }); };
```

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but this is pretty fun: http://framesynthesis.com/drivingsimulator/maps/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the v3 API you have to init a [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsService), create a [request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest) and parse the returned [Route object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRoute).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eq1h9LLa/) is a Fiddle-Example on how to do the very basic:

- A button click calls the function `calcRoute()`, which creates a request with the minimum mandatory parameters `from, to, mode` and queries the service.
- If the service returns a route, it calls `createPolyline()`, which creates a polyline with the coordinates in the `overview_path` array, creates a circle at the starting point and calls the function ..
- `animate()`, which changes the icon (=circle) offset along the polyline.

Hope that's enough to start with ;)
If you want a car instead of the circle, you have to define a custom icon.
If you don't want to loop it, stop the animation at the destination coordinates.
If you want to sum up distance/time, you have to parse the `steps` in the route-object.
[..]

You can uncomment line nr. 28 and copy the json to an [online formatter](https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) and get a better look at the structure of the response-object.

---

**EDIT:**

- Custom icon:
  To use a custom (SVG) icon, just copy the svg-path into the `path` paramter of the icon object.
  e.g.:

  ```
  path: 'M -1,0 A 1,1 0 0 0 -3,0 1,1 0 0 0 -1,0M 1,0 A 1,1 0 0 0 3,0 1,1 0 0 0 1,0M -3,3 Q 0,5 3,3'
  ```

  for that funky smileyface from the google examples ;)
- Stop condition:
  easiest way would be to query the `offset` result and cancel the `Intervall` at 100%.
  e.g.:

  ```
  if (count >= 199) { clearInterval(myAnimation); };
  ```
- `document.getElementById('Gresponse').innerHTML = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;`
  outputs the distance for me.
  The html page isn't very well formatted ... you may have to look right to the map above the routing-steps.
- The path for the parameters of the routing-steps is: `response.routes[0].legs[0].steps[i].instructions` with "i" incrementing over the step#

=> [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymirsson/70bo92kv/)

Comment: For JSON array which came from direction this link is use full
http://www.map4app.com/docs/directions-api/

Comment: the interval is the speed of animation icon ?
becasuse with small values go fast and big values go slow

Comment: The animation speed consists of two parts: 1) **how far** one step takes you comes from the modulo operation (in this case: .5% per step) 2) **how often** those animation steps occur. That's the interval parameter of the `setInterval()` function (in ms)